# Use internal pull-ups for row/column key scanning with diodes

Tags: diodes

I'm writing some microcontroller software to read a mechanical keyboard, which has diodes to prevent keys from interfering with each other.

The keyboard has the keys set up with row outputs and column inputs that can be scanned; basically the boxed area in this schematic, but with many more keys:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd28rV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Rows `R0`, `R1`, and columns `C0`, `C1` are GPIO pins on my microcontroller, AT90USB1286 (8-bit AVR).

I have limited understanding of actual electronics and don't really know how to use diodes effectively. I believe I could scan the keys using the following (naive) process:

1. Set `R0` to output high, all others low
2. Read all `Cn` pins to find out which `R0` keys are pressed
3. Repeat for `R1`, `R2`, etc.

For that to work, my understanding is that each column would need to have a pull-down resistor to prevent floating signals when no column keys are pressed. My microcontroller has optional internal pull-ups on every GPIO pin but no pull-downs, so I would need to add them myself. I don't believe I could use the pull-ups and change the scanning row output to low because the diodes will prevent the low signal from reaching the column input.

However, I am wondering if I could swap the row and column roles:

1. Enable internal pull-ups on all `Rn`
2. Set `C0` to output low, all others high (or hi-z?)
3. Read all `Rn` pins to find out which `C0` keys are pressed
4. Repeat from 2 for `C1`, `C2`, etc.

This would mean that my schematic would use `R0` and `R1` as inputs with pullups enabled, and `C0`/`C1` as outputs; each one would output low when scanning it.

My primary concern is that the diodes will somehow prevent the low output from overriding the pull-ups, or something like that.

Does this approach work?  Should I output high on the column pins that I'm not scanning, or is it okay (or better) to make them hi-z/inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. If Cn is 0V, the diode will conduct, and at the switched point Rm there will be the diode's forward voltage. make sure it is bellow the MCU's Vin low threshold.

Comment: Which means a minimum supply of 2.4V given CMOS thresholds (Vdd * 0.3).